# How to use the exclude filter syntax in Xpath

Tags: html, web, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a HTML from my firm by using Xpath, and here are the sample html structure of my target website:

```
<div class='my_target' id='A'>
    This is a sample website HTML!
    <span>APPLE</span>

    <span>BANANA</span>

    <span>ORANGE</span>

    <span>IGNORE_1</span>

    <span>IGNORE_2</span>

</div>


<div class='not_my_target' id='B'>
    This is a sample website HTML!
    <span>APPLE</span>

    <span>BANANA</span>

    <span>ORANGE</span>

    <span>IGNORE_1</span>

    <span>IGNORE_2</span>
</div>
```

And here are the elements I want to get:

```
<div class='my_target' id='A'>
This is a sample website HTML!
    <span>APPLE</span>

    <span>BANANA</span>

    <span>ORANGE</span>
</div>
```

I've tried the code like:

```
//div[@id='A' and (not(self::span and contains(text(), "IGNORE_1")) or not(self::span and contains(text(), "IGNORE_2"))]
```

But it didn't work Q_Q

Did I write a wrong syntax ? Any one could help ?

Thanks

Comment: You want to select the `span` elements inside the `div` or `span`s and the `div` too?

Comment: @Prophet I want to select the whole <div A>, and exclude the two "IGNORE_x" <span> elements.

Comment: With XPath you can get element with **all** its children only. Otherwise you need to use XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
//div[@id='A']/span[not(contains(text(),'IGNORE_1')) and not(contains(text(),'IGNORE_2'))]
```

This will search for the ID value of `A` and then check span for not containing  `IGNORE_1` and `IGNORE_2`.

**Problem with your case:**

You are searching for ID and setting conditions that it shouldn't contain `span`, `IGNORE_1` and `IGNORE_2`. That's why you are unable to get the desired result.

```
//div[@id='A' and (not(self::span and contains(text(), "IGNORE_1")) or not(self::span and contains(text(), "IGNORE_2"))]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried your code, but I found that the xpath can only catch the three <span> elements correctly, the sentence 'This is a sample website HTML!' won't show up. Is there any way to include this sentence ? THX